# Understanding the . and & operator

Tags: alloy

I'm having trouble understanding how these operators work. The Problem is the following: I have basically written this

```
abstract sig Statement {
    predecessor: lone Statement
    --...
}
sig Assignment extends Statement{
    --...
}
--Statements have unique prdecessors
fact { all disj s, t: Statement | s.predecessor & t.predecessor = none }
```

But then when I run it, I get this:
this/Statement<:predecessor={Assignment$0->Assignment$1, Assignment$1->Assignment$1, ... }

Now how I understand it is, s.predecessor and t.predecessor should take the predecessor relation and project out the first element (s and t respectively), meaning Assignment$0.predecessor should yield {Assignment$1} and Assignment$1.predecessor should yield {Assignment$1} also. Then taking the <s>union</s> intersection (&) of those should definitely not be none, so it contradicts the fact and should not show up.

Could you explain where I went wrong?

Thanks

Edit:

Here is all the code. It's quite long and there are some other issues, but the parts in question are in there. I can't see how anything could affect the fact though. The issue can be seen on the first example when running it (on my machine anyways).

```
//Signatures

//specification

--Expressions
abstract sig Expr{
    type: one Type,
    subExprs: set Expr
}

--Literals
sig Literal extends Expr{}
{ no subExprs }

--Variables
sig Variable{
    type: Type
}

--Functions
sig Function{
    statements: set Statement,
    returnType: one Type,
    params: set FormalParameter
}

--Statements
abstract sig Statement {
    exprs: set Expr,
    predecessor: lone Statement
}

--Variable Declarations
sig VarDecl extends Statement{
    var: Variable
}
{ no exprs }

--Types
sig Type{
    super: lone Type
}

--Formal Parameters
sig FormalParameter{
    type: Type,
    var: Variable
}

//more

--Call Expressions
sig CallExpr extends Expr{
    funct: Function,
    mapping: subExprs -> FormalParameter
}
//not modeled: order of parameters is the same as order of exprs

--Varaible References
sig Reference extends Expr{
    var: Variable
}
{ no subExprs }

--Return Statement
sig Return extends Statement{}
{ one exprs }

--Variable Assignment
sig Assignment extends Statement{
    var: Variable
}
{ one exprs }

--Main Function
one sig Main extends Function{}  




//==========================================================================
//Functions

//specification

--number of function calls in the program
fun p_numFunctionsCalls[]: Int{
    #CallExpr
}

--returns the types of all expressions
fun p_literalTypes[]: set Type{
    Expr.type // not sure if multiples allowed
}

--Returns all statements directly contained in the body of a function
fun p_statementsInFunction[f: Function]: set Statement{
    f.statements
}

--Returns all statements contained after s in the same function
fun p_statementsAfter[s: Statement]: set Statement{
    { fs: Statement | s in fs.^predecessor } 
}

--Returns the formal parameters of function f
fun p_parameters[f: Function]: FormalParameter{
    {ps: f.params}
}

--Returns the direct subexpressions of e
fun p_subExprs[e: Expr]: set Expr{
    e.subExprs
}

//more

--Returns all Expression in a function
fun p_funExprs[f: Function]: set Expr{
     p_statementExprs[f.statements]
}

--Returns all callExpressions in a function
fun p_funCallExprs[f: Function]: set CallExpr{
    { ce: CallExpr | ce in  p_funExprs[f]}
}

--Returns all exprs in s
fun p_statementExprs[s: Statement]: set Expr{
    s.exprs.*subExprs
}

--Returns all references in statements
fun p_statementReferences[s: Statement]: set Reference{
    { r: Reference | r in s.p_statementExprs }
}

--Returns all variable Declarations in f
fun p_funVarDecls[f: Function]: set VarDecl{
    { vd: VarDecl | vd in f.statements }
}

--Returns all variables declared in f
fun p_funVars[f: Function]: set Variable{
    { v: Variable | v in f.p_funVarDecls.var }
}

--return all subTypes of t and t itself
fun p_subTypes[t: Type]: set Type{
    { st: Type | t in st.*super }
}


//==========================================================================
//Predicates

//specification

--true iff f contains a function call directly in its body
pred p_containsCall[f: Function]{
    { some ce: CallExpr | ce in f.statements.exprs.*subExprs }
}

--true iff v appears on the left side of an assignment anywhere the program
pred p_isAssigned[v: Variable]{
    v in Assignment.var
}

--true iff v appears in an expression anywhere the program
pred p_isRead[v: Variable]{
    v in Reference.var
}

--true iff v is declared exactly once
pred p_isDeclared[v: Variable]{
    { all disj a, b: VarDecl | v = a.var implies v != b.var }
}

--true iff v is declared as a parameter
pred p_isParameter[v: Variable]{
    { all vd: VarDecl | v not in vd.var }//FIXME: variable might not be declared at all
}

--true iff t1 is a subtype of t2
pred p_subtypeOf[t1: Type, t2: Type]{
    t1 in t2.super
}

--true iff s assigns to the variable declared by vd
pred p_assignsTo[s: Statement, vd: VarDecl]{
    { all a: Assignment | s in a implies vd.var = a.var }
}

//more

//==========================================================================
//Facts

--All statements are in functions
fact { all s: Statement | s in Function.statements }

--Statements unique to functions
fact { all s: Statement, disj f, g: Function |  s in f.statements implies s not in g.statements }

--Statement predecessors are in same function
fact { all s: Statement, f: Function | s in f.statements implies s.p_statementsAfter in f.statements }

--Statements have unique prdecessors
fact { all disj s, t: Statement | s.predecessor & t.predecessor = none }


--return is always last
fact { all r: Return, f: Function | r in f.statements implies r.^predecessor = f.statements - r} 

--return has the same type as function its in
fact { all r: Return, f: Function | r in f.statements implies r.exprs.type in f.returnType.p_subTypes }



--assignments are only used after vars are declared
fact { all a: Assignment, vd: VarDecl | a.var in vd.var implies a in vd.p_statementsAfter }

--assignment and variable type match
fact { all a: Assignment | a.subExprs.type = a.var.type.p_subTypes }


--references only reference variables of the same function
fact { all r: Reference, f: Function | r in f.p_funExprs implies (r.var in f.params.var  or  r.var in f.p_funVars) }

--references only reference declared variables, all variables are referenced
fact { all f: Function | p_statementReferences[f.statements].var = f.p_funVars }

--type of the reference is type of the variable
fact { all r: Reference | r.type in r.var.type.p_subTypes }



--all functions have a return
fact { all f: Function | Return & f.statements != none }

--all functions but main are called
fact { all f: Function | f not in Main implies f in CallExpr.funct }

--recursion is not allowed
fact { all f: Function | f not in f.p_funCallExprs.*funct }


--each expression only in one statement
fact { all disj s, t: Statement | s.p_statementExprs & t.p_statementExprs = none }

--all expressions in statements
fact { all e: Expr | e in p_statementExprs[Statement] }

--expression not in its subExprs
fact { all e: Expr | e not in e.^subExprs }

--subExpressions unique
fact { all disj c, d, e: Expr | c in d.subExprs implies c not in e.subExprs }


--main never called
fact { Main not in CallExpr.funct }

--main has no params
fact { Main.params = none }


--types not supertytes of themselves
fact { all t: Type | t not in t.^super }


--variables always declared in either callExprs or varDecls
fact { all v: Variable | (v in VarDecl.var iff v not in FormalParameter.var) and (v in FormalParameter.var iff v not in VarDecl.var) }

--variables only declared once in varDecls
fact { all disj u, v: VarDecl | u.var != v.var }

--variables only declared once as parameters / parameters map to unique variable
fact { all disj fp1, fp2: FormalParameter | fp1.var != fp2.var }

--variables have the same type as corresponding param
fact { all fp: FormalParameter | fp.type = fp.var.type }

--declared variables are used always after the declaration and never before
fact { all vd: VarDecl | vd.var in vd.p_statementsAfter.p_statementReferences.var and  vd.var not in vd.^predecessor.p_statementReferences.var }


--parameters are never assigned to
fact { all fp: FormalParameter | fp.var not in Assignment.var }

--all parameters are in functions
fact { all fp: FormalParameter | fp in Function.params }

--params are unique to functions
fact { all fp: FormalParameter, disj f, g: Function | fp in f.params implies fp not in g.params }


--only params of function are mapped to
fact { all ce: CallExpr, expr: ce.subExprs | ce.mapping[expr] in ce.funct.params }

--callExprs have correct type
fact { all ce: CallExpr | ce.type = ce.funct.returnType }

--types of mapping are correct
fact { all ce: CallExpr, expr: ce.subExprs, p: ce.funct.params | ce.mapping[expr] = p implies expr.type = p.type }

--callExpr mapping is unique
fact { all ce: CallExpr, disj expr1, expr2: ce.subExprs | ce.mapping[expr1] != ce.mapping[expr2] }

--all subExprs are being mapped
fact { all ce: CallExpr | #ce.subExprs = #ce.funct.params } 


/*
--references have the same type as their variable
fact { all r: Reference | r.type = r.var.type }


*/


//==========================================================================
//Assertions



//==========================================================================
//Run

pred show{ all ce: CallExpr | #ce.subExprs >= 2}
pred show2{#Literal >= 3}
run {show2}
```

Answer (score 2):

When I run your model on Alloy 4.2, I do not see any error. Perhaps you may want to share the complete model here.

About taking the union, you will need to use the correct operator `+` for that. `&` is for intersection.

You can consult the [alloy language reference](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/book-chapters/alloy-language-reference.pdf) for basic syntax:

> · e1 + e2: union of e1 and e2;
>   · e1 - e2: difference of e1 and e2;
>   · e1 & e2: intersection of e1 and e2;

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong word, I meant intersection. The complete code is quite long, so I didn't post it. Still, the part I in question is in there and I can't see how anything could affect the fact. I posted all the code now for completeness.

Comment: I get this [output](http://pastebin.com/r8iNthhv) but not the error you have described in the question.

Comment: Well, this is strange. If I use only the part in question, the problem does indeed not show up. However, it finds the instance for the whole code, character by character as it is in my post. Maybe you have set the scope too low? Or a bug in the Sat Solver / Alloy that could be platform specific?

Comment: I get the same output as @k4rtik but if I change the last line to "run {show2} for 5" then I get "Instance found. Predicate is consistent.".